# How to use HTTP request's delete method in Laravel to delete item via external API library

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest

I'm using Zotero's API to get items from my (zotero) library and save them in my database.

When I click on the submit button, data is saved but I would like to delete it at the same moment from the online zotero's library whith the http request's delete method.

Here's what the API doc says about the delete:

> URI: `/keys/<key>`
> The user id and privileges of the given API key.
> Use the DELETE HTTP method to delete the key. This should generally be done only by a client that created the key originally using OAuth.

JSON structure of the data looks like this:

[image: structure]

Here's my controller:

```
public function index(Request $req){

    $response = Http::withToken('MyApiKey')->get('https://api.zotero.org/users/myUserID/items?limit=100
        ');
        $response->json();
        $datas= json_decode($response);
    return view('partials.ajout_automatique',compact('datas'));

}
```

My view:

```
@foreach ($datas as $data)

{{-- {{dd(property_exists($data->data,'title'))}} --}}

@if (property_exists($data->data,'title'))
    

<form action="/reference/autoCreate" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div>
       

        {{-- Title --}}

        @if (property_exists($data->data,'title'))
        <p>Titre: {{$data->data->title}}</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{$data->data->title}}" >
        @else
        <p>Titre not found</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="title unfound" >
        @endif

{{-- etc... --}}

<button type="submit" name='Ajouter' value="Ajouter"
        class="btn btn-success pl-5 pr-5">Ajouter</button>
</form>

@endif
@endforeach
```

My function store :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$response = Http::withToken('ItxwU6wG7bnNDY3E9bVfq3Da')->get('https://api.zotero.org/users/8548265/items?limit=100
    ');
    $response->json();
    $collections= json_decode($response);

        $reference_auto = new Reference;
        $reference_auto->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $reference_auto->title = $request->title;
        $reference_auto->authors = $request->authors;
        $reference_auto->year = $request->year;
        $reference_auto->edition = $request->edition;
        $reference_auto->url = $request->url;
        
            $message = "Nouvelle référence ajoutée avec succès."; 
            
          
            $reference_auto->save();
            Alert::success('Ok !', $message);

        
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I have no idea how and where I should use the `Http::delete('http://example.com');`
to achieve what I need to do.
For example to delete the first item I'm trying this in the store function before the redirect()->back()

```
   //delete from api lib
    $key=$collections[0]->key;
    Http::withToken('MyApiKey')->delete('https://api.zotero.org/users/MyUserID/items/keys/'.$key);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where to use that call depends on your logic. Usually, you could call it anywhere. But what do you mean by "it doesnt work"? Is the request not built properly? Not sent properly? Does it return any error?

Comment: Seeing what im trying to do, i think i have to use it in my store function. When i say it doesnt work I mean It returns no error but the delete isn't proccessed

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're using is incorrect. For single item deletion you should send a DELETE request to

```
'https://api.zotero.org/users/MyUserID/items/' . $key
```

You also need to include `If-Unmodified-Since-Version` header in your request. Please see https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/web_api/v3/write_requests

Also it is always worth checking HTTP code returned by the API to detect problems, e.g. `400 Bad Request` means that the request you've sent is incorrect, on the other hand `428 Precondition Required` means that the request was understood but (in this particular case) a required `If-Unmodified-Since-Version` header was not provided.